# Error: Package subpath './lib/utils' is not defined by "exports" in

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, javascript, hardhat

```
yasstns@DESKTOP-LJ7VL5E:~/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc$ yarn hardhat
yarn run v1.22.15
warning package.json: No license field
$ /home/yasstns/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/.bin/hardhat
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: Package subpath './lib/utils' is not defined by "exports" in /home/yasstns/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/ethers/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:453:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:731:3)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/yasstns/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/@ethereum-waffle/provider/src/CallHistory.ts:2:1) {
```

[image: ERROR IN TERMINAL]

[image]

**Here I've tried to replace "Import" to "export". But it didn't worked...**

```
"./utils": {
      "import": "./lib.esm/utils/index.js",
      "default": "./lib.commonjs/utils/index.js"
    },
    "./wallet": {
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I just had the same issue with thirdweb SDK.

Simply remove ethers@6 and add ethers@5, there are serious breaking changes in the new version and I suppose most libs do not support it.